# sending drop-down value to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-select

I have this form on my parent:

```html
<template>
  <b-form @submit="onSubmit">
    <CountryDropdown/>
  </b-form>
</template>

<script>
import ...

export default {
  form: {
    country: ''
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my Dropdown component using `vue-select`:

```html
<template>
  <v-select label="countryName" :options="countries" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      countries: [
        { countryCode: 'EE', countryName: 'Estonia' },
        { countryCode: 'RU', countryName: 'Russia' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I need to pass the `countryCode` value to its parent's `form.country`. I tried using `$emit`, but I cant seem to figure out how upon selection
it will set the parent value, and not upon submit.

**EDIT:**

The submitted solutions work great, I'll add my solution here:

I added an input event to my v-select:

```
<v-select @input="setSelected"  ... />
```

in my script i define the selected and setSelected method :

```
data() 
  return 
    selected: ''

setSelected(value) {
 this.selected = value.countryCode
 this.$emit("selected", value.countryCode)
}
```

And in the parent:

```
 <CountryDropdown v-on:selected="getCountry />
```

and parent script:

```
 getCountry(country) {
   this.form.country = country
 }
```

Comment: $emit('emitted') will emit an event you have to listen to in the parent: @emitted

Answer (score 2):

You could use Vue's [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) mechanism to bind the output of `vue-select` to `form.country` in the container.

In `CountryDropdown`, implement `v-model`:

1. Add a `prop` named `value` 1️⃣, and bind it to `vue-select.value` 2️⃣
2. Emit `input`-event with the desired value. In this case, we want to emit `countryCode` as the value. 3️⃣

```html
<template>
  <v-select
    :value="value" 2️⃣
    @input="$emit('input', $event ? $event.countryCode : '')" 3️⃣
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'], // 1️⃣
}
</script>
```

Now, the container of `CountryDropdown` could bind `form.country` to it, updating `form.country` to the selected country's `countryCode` upon selection:

```html
<CountryDropdown v-model="form.country" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-cloud-vrbjl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FCountryDropdown.vue&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know, $emit is what you need to use to send an event from a component to its' parent. To make that happen you need to add a few more things to your current code.

To get the options to list in your v-select you should use a computed function to isolate the names, like this:

```
computed: {
    countryNames() {
      return this.countries.map(c => c.countryName)
    }
  },
```

You will then need to list the names in your v-select like this:

```
<v-select label="countryName" :items="countryNames" @change="selectedCountry" />
```

You will see that @change is calling a method, this will be the method to emit your country code and it can do so like this:

```
methods: {
    selectedCountry(e) {
      let code = this.countries.find(cntry => cntry.countryName === e)
      this.$emit('code', code.countryCode)
    }
  },
```

You will need a listener in your parent to hear the emit, so add something like this:

```
<CountryDropdown v-on:code="countryCodeFunction"/>
```

And then you just need a countryCodeFunction() in your methods that does something with the emitted code.